# Display a page with a Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon

Can someone please tell me how to write a Firefox extension that displays a local HTML page (contained in the extension) when a user opens a new tab or web page.

Comment: Where do you want this page to be displayed?

Comment: @Neil On the blank page of the browser (when a user opens a new tab).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need this function to read a file inside your addon

```
function Read(file)
{
    var ioService=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
    var scriptableStream=Components
        .classes["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"]
        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableInputStream);

    var channel=ioService.newChannel(file,null,null);
    var input=channel.open();
    scriptableStream.init(input);
    var str=scriptableStream.read(input.available());
    scriptableStream.close();
    input.close();
    return str;
}
```

Then create an element and add the content of the HTML.

```
gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    var documentElement = e.originalTarget.defaultView.document;
    var div = documentElement.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = Read("chrome://extensioname/content/file.html");
    documentElement.body.appendChild(div);
});
```

Use `e.originalTarget.defaultView.location.href` to filter the pages you want this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm really new to Firefox add-ons and reading their tutorial all day I don't know what to put in Chrome manifest, install.rdf, etc. Could you please post the entire code or send me the code to my e-mail (bruno.da_silva@voila.fr)

Comment: @Bruno I can't right now. Try looking at the `Hello World` extension http://mozilla.doslash.org/stuff/helloworld.zip available at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/building_an_extension

Comment: We're here to help, but we're not free labor

Comment: @Iwburk When I was asking for the code I wasn't asking for all the code. What I meant is a code example of how to write an extension (with its hierarchy) that modifies the value of the default blank window (because in the official tutorials they only speak about Chrome which only works for the menus)

Answer (score 0):

You may find some info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners and https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Code_snippets/On_page_load .

To display HTML content inside XUL content (though you can also cause a pure XHTML dialog to open), you can use a [XUL iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/iframe)

Answer (score 0):

If you override the `BrowserOpenTab` function you can make it open the page of your choice rather than `about:blank`. This could be a page provided by your extension; ideally you would implement an alternative about URI for it.